# How to process a zip file in a browser

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, web-applications

I am writing a web app that allows people analysis a bunch of text files. The current solution that I am using is to upload the zip file to my server and that unzip -> load -> analysis -> result.

However, the some of the text files may have some privacy problem and server storage problem that I don't want to involve.

Is that any way to allow ppl upload the zip file and process it locally but not upload any file to my server.

Which keyword should I search for?

Answer (score 1):

The keywords you can use to search for such a library are "frontend javascript X". I searched "frontend javascript zip" and found this library.

Looks like it does exactly what you need.

https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/